# libcurl corrupting data when downloading file

Tags: c++, curl, fopen

I want to download some zip files with the curl library (c++) in visual studio 2013. The download with my code seems to work well, at least that's what the verbose aoutputs says. The file is always a bit bigger than the actual file and the files are always "corrupted", so I tried it with some text files and it seems to randomly add some lines at the start/end of the document and also make random spaces / destroys formating. Here is the curl part of my code:

```
//NOTE "CURL *curl" has already been used for previous requests and holds some cookies, so I won't paste the whole code here
//
//write to file function
size_t write_file(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

void download_file(string file_id){
    cout << "attempting to download file_id: " << file_id<< "\n";

    errno_t err; //error placeholder
    FILE * dl_file;

    string url = "http://foo.com/"; //base url

    string path_to_beatmap_file = "C:\\Users\\foo\\Desktop\\";
    string file_extension = ".txt";
    string full_filepath = path_to_beatmap_file + beatmap_id + file_extension;


    if (curl){
        cout << "attempting to download file to: " << full_filepath.c_str() << "\n";

        err = fopen_s(&dl_file, full_filepath.c_str(), "w+");
        if (err != 0){
            cout << "error: could not create file\n";
            return;
        }

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //need this since 1 redirect
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_file);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, dl_file);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //shows some debug output
        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); //execute download request
    }
    else{
        cout << "error: could not download file, no connection avaible\n";
        return;
    }




    cout << "\n\ndownloaded\n";


    if (fclose(dl_file) == 0){ cout << "closed the stream to file"; }
    else{ cout << "failed closing file"; }
}
```

If I open the txt file in notepad++ it shows a bunch of null or sub values at the end / start of the file, but I don't seem to be able to paste them here.

help is much appreciated.

**Update:**
seems like the random text added are some random ASCII characters (I used a debug function to print the output in a console and there were some arrow-right characters, but I don't think I can solve this by removing all arrow-right characters only). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using the "wb" parameter (write-binary) on fopen (also works same on fopen_s) solved all formating issues and everything works well now.